# Users with read and write for their data and write only privileges for the data added by others?

Tags: postgresql, openai-api, superuser

Is there anyone who can help me with creating a user with pgAdmin where I want to give them the privileges to read and write on their data but only read on the data added by other users?

I tried

```sql
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER "User A"
IN SCHEMA Zoning
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO "User B";
```

and

To grant a user permission to add data to a particular schema and edit and view only the data they have added, you can follow these steps:

- Create a new user with a password using the following SQL command:
  `CREATE USER new_user WITH PASSWORD 'your_password';`
  Replace `new_user` with the username you want to create and `your_password` with the password you want to use.
- Grant the new user permission to connect to the database using the following SQL command: `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE your_database TO new_user;`
  Replace `your_database` with the name of the database you want to grant access to.
- Grant the new user permission to create tables, sequences, and other objects in the schema using the following SQL command: `GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA your_schema TO new_user;`
  Replace `your_schema` with the name of the schema you want to grant access to.
- Grant the new user permission to insert data into tables in the schema using the following SQL command: `GRANT INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA your_schema TO new_user;`
  Replace `your_schema` with the name of the schema you want to grant access to.
- Create a new role for the user using the following SQL command: `CREATE ROLE new_user_role;`
- Grant the new role permission to select, update, and delete data in tables where the user is listed as the owner using the following SQL command: `GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA your_schema TO new_user_role;`
- Assign the new role to the new user using the following SQL command: `GRANT new_user_role TO new_user;`

After executing these SQL commands, the `new_user` should have permission to add data to the specified schema, and they will have edit and view access only to the data they have added.

When the user adds new data to a table in the schema, they will automatically become the owner of that data. As the owner of the data, the user will be able to edit and delete that data, but they will not be able to edit or delete data added by other users.

Note that granting these permissions to a user gives them a significant amount of control over the data in the database. Make sure to only grant these permissions to users who need them and who you trust to handle the data responsibly.
this help from ChatGPT. But couldn't do it at all. I want to do this all by superuser.

Comment: That won't be possible through PostgreSQL itself, as it does not store which user added a row. Perform this kind of check in your application instead

Comment: Please don't copy/paste ChatGPT-generated documentation into a question. And when you *do* post things into a question, please be sure to format it for readability. You should take a look at the writeup about the [current ban on ChatGPT-generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Are you trying to restrict permissions by table or by row?  The code you have attempted will try to restrict permissions on a table or schema basis, but it's not clear if that's what you want or not.

Comment: You might want to lookup up multi-tenancy setups, [privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) and [row-level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html). Also, your first paragraph says you want a user to be able to ***read*** other users' data, while the title says you want the user to be only able to ***write*** over data added by others. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve and why, as well as what exactly went wrong with your previous attempts.